# как можно реализовать такую идею, но для N любого?

Tags: c#, массивы

```
int N = 3;
string s = ""; 
int[] arrayN = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    s = s + arrayN[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        s = s + arrayN[j];
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            Console.Write(s + arrayN[k] + "\n");
        }
        s = "";
        s = s + arrayN[i];
    }
    s = "";
}
```

---

Output:

```
111
112
113
121
122
123
131
132
133
211
212
213
221
222
223
231
232
233
311
312
313
321
322
323
331
332
333
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;

int N = 3;  //NB! не пытайтесь использовать большие N
int[] arrayN = Enumerable.Range(1, N).ToArray();  //если у нас ограниченый алфавит, то используем new int[]{1,2,3}  
string[] result = arrayN.Select(n => $"{n}").ToArray();  
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) 
{
    result = (from a in arrayN
              from b in result
              select $"{a}{b}").ToArray();  
}
```

*P.S. for @Андрей* для получения числовых результатов надо всего лишь поменять две строки

```
int[] result = arrayN;
...
select b*10 + a).ToArray();
```

Comment: Чтобы не материализовать результаты, можно переделать под рекурсию по идее.

Comment: @VladD, на рекурсию вроде бы уже дан ответ

Comment: хм, и правда :)

Comment: Крутой вариант! Жаль вот чтоб результаты были числовые и в том же порядке не так просто сделать. (Хотя можно сортировать после получения всего массива, но это мне не очень нравится) Можно написать `select b * 10 + a`, но тогда порядок другой...

Comment: @Андрей, сделал для вас дополнение

Comment: @Mirdin, ну это я и сам написал, только вот порядок вывода не такой как у автора: `111 211 311 ...`

Comment: @Андрей, ну... если нужен конкретный порядок, то нужно будет писать свою функцию сортировки. Ну или как вариант парсить строки.

Comment: @Mirdin подскажи, а как в c# запустить? он ругается на .Select и то что стоит в скобках result.

Comment: @d1mazty, какими словами ругается?

Comment: @Mirdin как я понял именно на $, а ругается "Unexpected character '$' " но там еще дополнительно есть, но я думаю проблема в этом

Comment: @d1mazty 1. вверху у вас должна быть строчка `using System.Linq;` 2. На какой версии VS вы пишете?

Comment: @d1mazty, если проблема в $ замените всю строку на `select String.Format("{0}{1}", a, b)).ToArray();`, а `$"{n}"` на `n.ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

```js
function combinations(arr, level, text) 
{
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    var out = text + "" + arr[i];
    if (level < arr.length - 1)
      combinations(arr, level + 1, out);
    else
      document.write(out + "<br/>");
  }
}

combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0, "");
```

Comment: Для большей размерности массива не работает.

Comment: Это же js, а тег c#

Comment: Да даже если бы js, но сам алгоритм не делает то что надо.

Comment: @d1mazty будьте добры, укажите для какой размерности не работает. Алгоритм делает что надо.

Comment: Алгоритм делает именно то, что надо. Вложенные циклы заменены рекурсией, константа заменена размером массива. Шарп или js не так критично, зато js можно прямо здесь выполнить.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант без рекурсии (и на шарпе :) ):

```
int N = 5;
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int C = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) C *= arr.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < C; ++i)
{
    int d = i;
    string s = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        s = arr[d % arr.Length] + s;
        d /= arr.Length;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

N - число разрядов на выходе, arr - массив возможных значений для разрядов

---

Тоже самое, но в виде генератора + на выходе числа, а не строки:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetCombinations(int n, int[] arr)
{
    if (n < 1) yield break;
    int count = arr.Length;
    int[] exp = new int[n];
    exp[0] = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        exp[j] = 10 * exp[j - 1];
        count *= arr.Length;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        int d = i;
        int k = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            k += arr[d % arr.Length] * exp[j];
            d /= arr.Length;
        }
        yield return k;
    }
}
```

Использовать можно так:

```
foreach (var k in GetCombinations(5, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }))
    Console.WriteLine(k);
```

Comment: По-моему строку `for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) C *= arr.Length;` можно заменить на `Math.Pow(N, arr.Length)`. Это должно работать быстрее цикла.

Comment: @Chloroform, можно, но там `double`, поэтому может быть не точно, ну и, скорее всего, не быстрее будет

Comment: Соглашусь, `Math.Pow()` тут не подойдёт

Answer (score 1):

А вот чисто математическое решение:

```
var N = 3;
var mask = Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(x => (int)Math.Pow(N, x)).Reverse().ToArray();
for (var i = 0; i < Math.Pow(N, N); i++)
{
    var number = string.Join("", mask.Select(x => (i / x % N + 1).ToString()))
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Вариант со словарем:

```
var N = 3;
var dictionary = new [] {"A", "B", "C"};
if (dictionary.Length < N) throw new InvalidOperationException("dictionary is not enough");
var mask = Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(x => (int)Math.Pow(N, x)).Reverse().ToArray();
for (var i = 0; i < Math.Pow(N, N); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", mask.Select(x => dictionary[i / x % N])));
}
```